# How to create lines with start and end points in Swift (ARKit, SCNKit)

Tags: swift, vector, line, arkit

I want to create a line that I can tell it where to start and where to end in a Scene in ARKit. Someone else made this class but I get errors. Something simple like startLine at node... and endLine at node... would be helpful. I feel like it shouldn't be so complicated to do a simple line between two points so if your answer is complicated please explain why it has to be. Thank you all for your help!

```
class LineNode: SCNNode {

private(set) var cylinder: SCNCylinder
private(set) var positionA: SCNVector3
private(set) var positionB: SCNVector3

init(with startingPoint: SCNVector3, endPoint: SCNVector3, radius: Float = 0.02, color: UIColor = .red) {
    self.positionA = startingPoint
    self.positionB = endPoint
    let vector = endPoint - startingPoint  *//error*
    let height = vector.length()
    cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: radius, height: Float(height))
    cylinder.radialSegmentCount = 8
    cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
    super.init()
    geometry = cylinder
    position = (endPoint + startingPoint) / 2   *//error*
    eulerAngles = SCNVector3.lineEulerAngles(vector: vector)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

// I get the error:Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'SCNVector3' operands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write an extension if you want to use '+/-' on a Vector. Just paste this under the class defintion.

```
class ... {
 // class code
}
func + (left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y, left.z + right.z)
}

func - (left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(left.x - right.x, left.y - right.y, left.z - right.z)
}
```

post it below the class bracket

Comment: The conversion works but then I get other errors on the code. I have a feeling this isn't the best way to approach this problem. Do you have any ideas on how to approach this? basically creating a 3d line in ARKit that connect two 3d objects? seems like there would be a drawLine() method somewhere but I've spend so much time reading the documentation and I'm not getting anywhere. Seems that I'm reading in the wrong places or I just dont understand or both. Anyway, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out the Boxify Project on Github? ```self.lineDA.setPosition(from: point, distance: size.z , axis: .z) ``` and the set Position Function looks like that: ``` ...  let absDistance = CGFloat(abs(distance))
        let offset = distance * 0.5
        switch axis {
        case .x:
            box.width = absDistance
            self.position = position + SCNVector3(x: offset, y: 0, z: 0)
        case .y:
           ..
        case .z:
            ...
        }

Answer (score 0):

SCNVector3 is a struct, not a class. You cannot apply '-' operator.

So we can create another SCNVector3 using old values.

```
let vector = SCNVector3(endPoint.x - startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y, startingPoint.z)
```